# timerSchedule does not obey the start timer set?

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have a test file with three lines, each line begins with a timestamp in seconds. I read this time stamp and based on it I schedule a new timer 
for each time stamp being read. Why, when I run the threads created in the method "processFile" mentioned below, does the console display the output of the three
timers at once? I expected to see the out put of each timer separated with few seconds delay between as the time stamp of each of the three lines i read
from the file are 2 seconds, 15 seconds and 7 seconds respectively? when i run the program, after few seconds i receive the below "system time" output 
all at once without delay separate them despite the timestamp being read from the file is different!

Kindly please let me know why what is happening and how to solve it.

```
//this method is being called on a worker thread

    private static void processFile(File dataFile) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(WORKER_THREAD + " started.");
    logfile = new MeasurementFile(dataFile, MeasurementFile.ENCODING_UTF_8);
    System.out.println("Total lines in the file: " + logfile.getTotalLines());
    System.out.println("#Parameters/line: " + logfile.getFileHash().get(logfile.getTotalLines()).getFullParameters().length);
    System.out.println("Time Stamp in Seconds: " + logfile.getFileHash().get(logfile.getTotalLines()).getTimeStampInSec());

    timer = new Timer();
    for (int i = 1; i <= logfile.getTotalLines(); i++) {
        ++currentLine;
        t = new Thread(new threadFile(), "logFile_Thread_" + i);
        t.start();
    }

}

static class threadFile implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        timer.schedule(new timedTask(), (long) logfile.getFileHash().get(currentLine).getTimeStampInMilli());
    }
}

static class timedTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long nanoTimer = System.nanoTime();
        //long milliTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("systemTime(ns): " + nanoTimer);
    }
}
```

**OutPut**:

```
file processing thread started.
Total lines in the file: 3
#Parameters/line: 9
Time Stamp in Seconds: 7.0
systemTime(ns): 4882255697670
systemTime(ns): 4882255928644
systemTime(ns): 4882255985104
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with `MeasurementFile`. How is that reading the times off each line, and are you sure it's not failing and defaulting to 0?

Comment: that ile is a class the process a file and parse the data line by line and then parse values from each line.

Comment: You should probably output the value it takes from each line to make sure its parsing correctly. Otherwise I can't see an issue with your code.

Comment: @Rudi sorry i could not understand what did u mean by "You should probably output the value it takes from each line"?

Comment: `System.out.println(logfile.getFileHash().get(currentLine).getTimeStampInMilli());` That way you can check to make sure your getting the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the for-loop and the counter inside it and the way you create a n ew instance of the thread.
I would do it that way.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= logfile.getTotalLines(); i++) {
    t = new Thread(threadFile, "logFile_Thread_" + i);
    t.start();
}

static Runnable threadFile = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ++currentLine;
        timer.schedule(new timedTask(), (long)  
        logfile.getFileHash().get(currentLine).getTimeStampInMilli());
    }
};
```

Because the counter in the for-loop, will get always its maximum value wihch will be applied to all the  Timertasks. in other words, if yu have a loop for 5 iterations the counter will get its maximum value depending on how the counter was initalised and then this counter values you use it to parse a specific datat from your file which means you alwas get the value frm the last line then apply it to the timerTask

Comment: Well spotted. I didn't even notice he was using `currentLine` across contexts and threads.

Comment: You are right that there is a race on that particular variable. However, your method doesn't solve that race, as the `++currentLine` part is not synchronized.

Comment: So long as `currentLine` isn't incremented anywhere else, you could ensure no race condition by adding the increment into the call. `.get(++currentLine).` That said, you're probably just better off synchronizing. Less likely to break in future that way.

Comment: @Rudi what do you mean there is nobody else accessing it? Three threads have been created, all of them running that runnable, and incrementing that counter.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - I just meant that incrementing **during** the call to the only methods that are using it (the get() method) you can ensure that it will be correct at the time of the call as long as it's only being altered during get() calls. It's a silly hack, I probably shouldn't have mentioned it.

Comment: @Rudi I think you are making a mistake (or maybe I am, so please correct me), by assuming the increment will happen inside the call. The thread will reach that line, do the `++currentLine`, and pass the result to `get()`. `get()` is called only after all the expressions passed to its parameters are calculated.

Comment: I retract my original statement. I was under the misplaced impression that the JVM executes a single line at a time. Which it does not.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve the race on `currentLine` differently:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= logfile.getTotalLines(); i++) {
    t = new Thread(new ThreadFile(i), "logFile_Thread_" + i);
    t.start();
}
```

Defining `ThreadFile` thus:

```
static class ThreadFile implements Runnable {

    private int lineToProcess;

    public ThreadFile( int lineToProcess ) {
         super();
         this.lineToProcess = lineToProcess;
    }

    public void run() {
        timer.schedule(new timedTask(), (long) logfile.getFileHash().get(lineToProcess).getTimeStampInMilli());
    }
}
```

This way, when you create the runnable, it already knows which line to access, and there is no access to a *common* variable and no need for synchronization.

There may still be some sort of a problem with `logfile` since it, too, is common and not synchronized, but if all we do is read from it and reading does not involve updating its state, it should be OK.